# Como fazer upload do backup do BD para o servidor usando Okhttp?

Tags: php, java, android, okhttp

Como fazer upload do arquivo .db (backup do SQLite), do dispositivo android para um servidor usando a biblioteca Okhttp, java e PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sussa!

Na [documentação do OkHttp Recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) existe algumas demostrações comuns. Mais especificamente, você terá que usar propriedades da classe `MultipartBody.Builder()` para o envio do arquivo.

No **[square/okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)** tem exatamente o que você quer ([`PostFile.java`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostFile.java)), porém para o que você precisa, fiz algumas alterações básicas. Vou te mostrar:

### JAVA

#### MyPostFile.java

Este é a classe que faz tudo acontecer, usando [**OkHttpClient**](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

```
public final class MyPostFile{

    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run() throws Exception {

        File file = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/bkp_sqlite.db");

        if (file.length() != 0) {

            MultipartBody.Builder requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8"), file));

            MultipartBody multBody = requestBody.build();    
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://api.meusite.com/file")
                    .post(multBody)
                    .build();

            try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Log.wtf(PostFile.class.getSimpleName(), response.body().string());
            }
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        new PostFile().run();
    }
}
```

#### Main.java

Veja abaixo como chamar o `MyPostFile`:

```
MyPostFile postFile = new MyPostFile();
try {
    postFile.run();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### PHP

Para receber o arquivo é utilizado o [`$_FILES`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php). Este recurso permite a realização de *uploads* de arquivos de texto e binários. A princípio é validado se o arquivo está em branco: `empty($_FILES)`, e se caso não esteja, é gerado um nome de arquivo usando data e hora: `date('YmdHis')`. Veja o código final abaixo:

```
if (empty($_FILES)) { // verifica se existe algum entrada de arquivo
        echo 'Erro ao enviar arquivo';
} else {   

    if (!empty($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] !== 4) { 
            if (!$_FILES['file']['error']) {

                $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $newfilename = "_".date('YmdHis') . '.' . end($temp);

                if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newfilename)) {
                    echo 'There is a error while processing uploaded file';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Erro ao enviar arquivo';
            }
    }
}
```

PS.: Para que tudo isso funcione corretamente, você não pode esquecer das permissões que devem ser concedida no `manifest.xml`.

Comment: Obrigado @Ack Lay, funcionou pra mim.

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos por nada... precisar, só chamar! =)